# Not able to spoof MAC address in Kali Linux

Tags: networking, kali-linux, mac-address, networkmanager, ifconfig

The MAC address is spoofed when the network interface is down or not connected to any AP. But as soon as I connect to any access point it changes the spoofed MAC address to the original address.

I tried the following to spoof my MAC address:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
macchanger -a wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Even tried to stop and start network-manager with the above command still nothing.

I also changed the MAC changer command with this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

And still no luck.

The `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` has stored the original MAC address and changes the spoofed address to the original. When I disconnect from the network, the MAC address is changed back to the spoofed address.

When I open the “Settings > Networks,” and go to the AP's settings, I am able to set a clone address and it works perfectly. But I want to be able to change the MAC address from the terminal itself, so I don’t always have to go to the settings to change it.

I even tried to forget the AP and set a new connections with spoofed MAC address, still it always seems to revert back to the original address.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same issue as yours after doing everything you did! I read this in the official [Kali Linux forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19529-MAC-Spoofing-WiFi-Device-and-Surfing-The-Net-Beware!!!).

Well I didn’t stop there as well and got around to it finally with below procedure and hopefully it will help you too.

1. Down everything `wlan`, `lo`, `eth`, etc…

   ```
   ifconfig wlan0 down
   ifconfig eth0 down
   ```
2. Stop service manager

   ```
   service network-manager stop
   ```
3. Add your address:

   ```
   ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:05
   ```
4. Start your service manager:

   ```
   service network-manager start
   ```
5. Un-block all:

   ```
   rfkill unblock all
   ```
6. Finally up your card:

   ```
   ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```

Then check if it worked by running this command:

```
ifconfig | grep ether
```

Hopefully you will then have something like this shown:

```
ether 00:00:00:00:00:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save this code in to a bash script (changeMac.sh) and try running it with elevated permissions (`sudo bash changeMac.sh`) when you wanna change the mac address.

```
service NetworkManager stop
ifconfig wlan0 down
macchanger -r wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 up
service NetworkManager start
```